# CruiseControl or CruiseControl.NET

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I've been using the latest release of CruiseControl.NET (1.6.7981.1). It works fairly well, but the web dashboard is not the greatest and I dislike how the service refuses to start if any of the projects files have incorrectly configured XML.

What are my options? How about using the main CruiseControl instead? Will it play nicely with MSBuild? Will it format the MSBuild results reasonably like the CruiseControl.NET "MSBuild Report"? I see that it hasn't had any releases since September 2010. Yikes. Is it essentially fully baked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CC.NET is really better** than CruiseControl, and lightweight.

If you need to change, first let's write your requirements and constraints of such continuous integration tool.
If you just need something 'nicer', and easier to use, then **consider switching to Jenkins**, as the configuration is mainly done with a web interface.

If you need custom reports, custom email or custom statistics, then continue with CC.NET.

And remember that you should always use **CCValidator.exe** located in CC.NET install folder to validate your configuration file(s).

Switching from one CI tool to another is easy, as you already have all the scripts to execute.

Comment: You're probably right. I was just looking around to see if there was anything "much better" out there.

Answer (score 3):

As a long-time user of cc.net, I'd recommend switching to Jenkins or TeamCity. I really like TeamCity, but Jenkins is trivial to configure and get running.

Comment: As a long term user of cc.net, could you elaborate on why the switch is worth it?

Comment: @Ralph - Several reasons, but the strongest is that CC.Net requires the creation and modification of a proprietary xml format to get projects up an running, whereas the other two systems provide a GUI. The latest version CC.Net has some 'features' (specifically: security and modules) that seem half baked. The last reason is that cc.net doesn't appear to have an active owner and hasn't been updated in over a year and a half.

Comment: thanks!, I'm use to modifying CC.Net config files and so I was interested in your perspective. I'm using Jenkins now too, its UI is great and there's lots of active development on it.

Comment: Yup. I want to cast a vote for Jenkins too. Jenkins supports feedback while builds are running and it doesn't restart the server when you make a configuration change to 1 project. The cc.net community is dying off, whereas Jenkins has a lively community. I'm still using CC.net, but looking to switch.