# Sample cruisecontrol.net ccnet.config that works with msbuild and delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, delphi-xe

I asked some time ago for help getting [continuous integration working in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313169/delphi-build-automation-and-continuous-integration-feasible-using-ms-build-only) previously. One side-answer has partial incomplete (not working for me) information [here][2] for using cruisecontrol.

I have gotten Jenkins/Hudson working, and the easy part about it is that (with Delphi) the configuration is done purely through the Web browser.  However with CruiseControl.net is much more difficult to set up.

I would like to see a sample ccnet.config that will build a hello-world delphi project (Project1.dproj) using MSBUILD, from CruiseControl, and auto-rebuild each time that the subversion (or mercurial) upstream sources are modified.

So far I have:

- installed and got CruiseControl.net version 1.6.7981 and its running.
- No valid projects in my `ccnet.config`

Here's my ccnet.config, originally I had `<exec>` and changed as suggested below to `<msbuild>`:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
        <!-- CRUISECONTROL.NET Server configuration -->
        <project name="Project1">
            <tasks>
                <msbuild>
                    <projectFile>project1.dproj</projectFile>
                </msbuild>
            </tasks>
        </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Update: I was originally unable to make it read `c:\builds\ccnet.config` from ccnet.exe but I found that I could run ccnet.exe (non-service mode) with a command line parameter and that got me around the problem finding my ccnet.config.

Comment: I don't think CC.NET is much more difficult to configure, if you know the **right** command line to execute, then the difference is creating a XML file (CC.NET) or click on web page (Jenkins). See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685102/cruisecontrol-or-cruisecontrol-net/9729765#9729765

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample configuration block for a project that is rebuild at 05:00 if modification exists:

```
<!-- DelphiCodeToDoc Project -->
<project name="DelphiCodeToDoc" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
  <category>Delphi</category>
  <artifactDirectory>$(ArtifactBaseDir)\DelphiCodeToDoc</artifactDirectory>
  <workingDirectory>$(WorkingBaseDir)\DelphiCodeToDoc</workingDirectory>
  <triggers>
    <scheduleTrigger time="05:00" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" name="Scheduled" />
  </triggers>

  <!-- SVN implementation -->
  <sourcecontrol type="svn">
    <trunkUrl>http://dephicodetodoc.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dephicodetodoc/trunk/DelphiCodeToDoc/</trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>$(WorkingBaseDir)\DelphiCodeToDoc</workingDirectory>
  </sourcecontrol>

  <!-- Build tasks to implement -->
  <tasks>

    <!-- Compile command-line application -->
    <msbuild>
      <executable>$(MSBuildPath)\MSBuild.exe</executable>
      <workingDirectory>$(WorkingBaseDir)\DelphiCodeToDoc\Source</workingDirectory>
      <projectFile>DCTD_cmd.dproj</projectFile>
      <buildArgs>/target:Build /p:Config=Debug</buildArgs>
      <timeout>900</timeout>
      <logger>$(MSBuildLogger)</logger>
    </msbuild>

  <!-- Publishing compiled results -->
  <publishers>
    <merge>
      <files>
        <file>$(ArtifactBaseDir)\DelphiCodeToDoc\buildlogs*.xml</file>
      </files>
    </merge>

  <!-- Statistics -->
    <xmllogger />
    <rss/>
    <statistics>
    </statistics>

  </publishers>
</project>
```

You can define variables `$(MSBuildPath)` in this way:

```
  <cb:define MSBuildPath="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5" />
```

Or replace it directly with the real path.

Comment: @WarrenP it is internally defined by CC.NET

Comment: @WarrenP oops, I made a mistake! You can define and use $(MSBuildPath) (edited reply). Concerning $(WorkingBaseDir), it's an internal definition. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `<exec>`, use this:

```
<msbuild>
  <projectFile>project1.dproj</projectFile>
</msbuild>
```

Add a trigger to your project:

```
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="30"
    buildCondition="IfModificationExists" initialSeconds="30" />
</triggers>
```

The rest should work.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your error message

> [CCNet Server:ERROR] INTERNAL ERROR: Access to the path 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\Project1\WorkingDirectory' is
>   denied.

you should define the working directory and the artifact directory **outside CC.NET installation**, something like `c:\builds`.

Comment: This would be better as a comment.

Comment: You changed the question so fast :)

Comment: Sorry. I try to keep history in the question enough that it makes sense, but sometimes I edit things too much.

Comment: How exactly does one "define [...] the artifact directory outside CC.NET installation" without having to do it for each project?